# Concatenate values when greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, concatenation

I'm needing to concatenate values from multiple columns if the value is greater than 0.

Example:

```
Video     1  
Internet  0  
Phone     3  
Security  0  
Basic     1
```

So the end value would be `1 Video|3 Phone|1 Basic|`

Is there a better way to do this than writing code like:

```
    Case When Video > 0 and Internet+Phone+Security+Basic < 0 Then Video + ' Video|' 
    When Video > 0 and Internet > 0 and Phone+Security+Basic < 0 Then Video + ' Video|' + Internet + ' Internet|' 
    When Video > 0 and Phone > 0 and Internet+Security+Basic < 0 Then Video + ' Video|' + Phone + ' Phone|'
```

and so on until every combination is accounted for.

Comment: u must hv googled first!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
  Case When Video > 0     Then Video +     ' Video|'     else '' end +
  Case When Internet  > 0 Then Internet  + ' Internet|'  else '' end +
  Case When Phone > 0     Then Phone +     ' Phone|'     else '' end +
  Case When Security > 0  Then Security +  ' Security|'  else '' end +
  Case When Basic > 0     Then Basic +     ' Basic|'     else '' end +
from source
```

Comment: Ah Duh! Thanks! That's the exact code I had on my first round of tests (but left out the Else '') and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working so I assumed I would have to go through every possible scenario.

Comment: @Doolius, `else` part should be not `null`, because when `else` part is left out, expression is 'video'+null+'phone'+null+'basic' will result in `null`